# wait_while_present not waiting and next element clicking

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

in my hooks.rb I have

```
Before do
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --test-type --disable-web-security --disable-extensions]
end
```

And in my account_home.rb page I have:

```
class AccountHome

  include PageObject

  button(:billtransfers, :id => 'nav_transfersPayments')

end
```

I am trying to wait until a div disappears before I click on an element:

```
When(/^the user navigates to Bills & Transfers \/ Vendors$/) do
  @browser.div(:id => 'spinner').wait_while_present
  on(AccountHome).billtransfers_element.when_present.billtransfers
  on(AccountHome).vendors
  sleep 5
end
```

but I keep getting the below error:

```
Element is not clickable at point (95, 254). Other element would receive the click: <div id="spinner" class="screenMask">...</div>
```

It does not seem to be waiting until the div with id 'spinner' is gone. Additionally, if I replace it with sleep instead of wait_while_present, it will wait but then this line:

```
on(AccountHome).billtransfers_element.when_present.billtransfers
```

I receive an error message that billtransfers is not a method.  I referred to this documentation https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Ajax-Calls

So overall, I just want to wait until the div is gone and then it clicks the button.  But 1. It is not waiting while present and not clicking the button when present.

Comment: `when_present` returns the element, which is why the `billtransfers` method does not exist. The wiki page is wrong or out-of-date. It should be `on(AccountHome).billtransfers_element.when_present.click`. In terms of why it is not waiting, I might guess that Watir checks that the spinner is not present, the spinner then gets rendered and then Watir tries to click. Perhaps the action that causes the spinner to appear need to wait for the spinner to appear. However, it is hard to know if that is the problem without seeing the page.

Comment: I suspect Justin is right about the spinner div. I'd add that element to my page object and try this: `on(AccountHome).spinner_element.when_present.wait_while_present`.

Comment: makes sense.  I just added a sleep 1 before the wait_while_present but I think when_present makes much more sense.  Thanks both!